# method in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I want to create a method in class `ArrayTest` and sort `arraylist` object.
But something is wrong:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ArrayTest{
    public static ArrayList<String> getSortedArrayList(String args[]){
        ArrayList<String> sort = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.sort(sort);
        return  sort;
    }
}
```

> **Syntax Error(s)**
>   **Tester**.java:20: error: method getSortedArrayList in class ArrayTest cannot be applied to giventypes;
>
> System.out.println(ArrayTest.getSortedArrayList("Mark","Andrew", "Beth"));;
>
> ```
>                          ^
> ```
>
> required: String[]
>
> found: String,String,String
>
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>
> 1 error

Comment: The error message you are recieving defenitly doesn´t result from the code beeing shown by you

Comment: words like "something" are very vague, please clarify exactly where it was saying the error and what the error was

Answer (score 0):

Your program is doing this:

```
ArrayList<String> sort = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.sort(sort);
return sort;
```

Take a look at it line-by-line:

1. Create a new `ArrayList<String>` (with no elements)
2. Sort the just created `ArrayList<String>`  (which has no elements)
3. Return the `ArrayList<String>` (which has no elements)

It seems like you want to have `String[] args` sorted, so you need to have these elements in your `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the call to

```
ArrayTest.getSortedArrayList(new String[]{ "Mark", "Andrew", "Beth" });
```

or, better, change method signature to use variable arguments:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getSortedArrayList(String ... args)
```

So `args` will be seen as a `String[]` (i.e. you can use `.length` and `[]`) and you can call it with `ArrayTest.getSortedArrayList("Mark", "Andrew", "Beth")`